# Generating a set of unique numbers/strings from a given string

Tags: algorithm, checksum, fingerprinting, string-hashing

I am working on a project where I need to assign some people with an unique ID.

Now I have this requirement that, based on those IDs, I need to generate a **set** of **unique numbers**. No two IDs should result in the same set, and the intersection of sets from any two IDs should be empty.

How am I supposed to achieve this?
Suggest an algorithm for this.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenete the unique ID and a unique serial number.

Depending on the situation, the serial number can be global, or can be assigned per ID.

E.g.

```
A1, B2, A3, C4, E5, A6, A7, B8...
```

vs.

```
A1, B1, A2, C1, E1, A3, A4, B2...
```